# How to interpret Firefox profiler result evaluation for non-JS code?

Tags: firefox, profiler

My `firefox` process randomly starts hogging one CPU core so I thought I'd give the new profiler a spin.

This screenshot is from a 5-second-profile (very cool feature!):

[image]

Is there any way to find out what these `fun_`s are?
How could I advance from here?

It appears that libxul is tightly bundled with Firefox so I hope get some information out of Firefox but, so far, I haven't found anything.

Side note - the journal also provides some clues but I'd like to try the Firefox way first.

```
Mar 04 12:32:52 couch-potassium systemd-journald[317]: [] Suppressed 17794486 messages from session-2.scope
Mar 04 12:32:52 couch-potassium firefox.desktop[1120]: Error: WaylandMessage::Write() too many files to send
Mar 04 12:32:52 couch-potassium firefox.desktop[1120]:  :
Mar 04 12:32:52 couch-potassium firefox.desktop[1120]: Error: WaylandMessage::Write() too many files to send
Mar 04 12:32:52 couch-potassium firefox.desktop[1120]:  :
Mar 04 12:32:52 couch-potassium firefox.desktop[1120]: Error: WaylandMessage::Write() too many files to send
```